# Edit one PowerPoint presentation on two monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint

I would like to edit my PowerPoint slides on one and have the slide overview on the other screen. I'm using Microsoft Office 2010 Professional on Microsoft Windows 7 x64.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that by "slide overview" you mean Slide Sorter view, do this:

Open your presentation

Choose View | New Window.  This will open a second window on the same presentation.

Put the second window into Slide Sorter view, arrange the two windows to suit and you're good to go.

Comment: Do you know if its possible to sync page? So, when page change in the main mointor, it changes in the secondary one.

Comment: Other than by forcing it manually, no.  That doesn't mean there ISN'T a way, just that I don' t know of any.  Sorry.